# Retrieving data from MySQL database using $_SESSION username

Tags: php, session, mysqli, syntax-error

I am new at PHP and I'm trying to create a profile page whereby the user is able to view their information which they inserted when signing up to the website.

At first I'm attempting this with just their first name, so that whoever is logged in can see what first name they have saved on the database.

I have a included "checklog.php" page which includes

```
<? php session_start(); ?>;
```

And in my page, when i use;

```
echo $_SESSION['username']
```

The user's username is printed out fine.

So i've tried to  apply this in mysqli query in order to print out their first name from the database like this;

```
<?php 

if($db_server){

               $query = "SELECT firstname FROM users WHERE username=$_SESSION['username']";     

               $result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or 

               die(mysql_error($db_server)); 

               if (!$result) die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error($db_server)); 

               while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 

                                                         echo $row['firstname'];

 }

 }

 mysqli_free_result($result);

 ?>
```

But I get an error on line 15 which is the SQL statement, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong in my statement?

Answer (score 0):

First of all add `session_start();` in the top of the PHP code..

```
<?php
session_start();//<-- Here
```

Second.. rewrite your query like this..

```
$query = "SELECT firstname FROM users WHERE username= '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have said, I have session_start(); included in my checklog.php page.

I've updated my query but now I get the following error message on the page;

Warning: mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in /home/cs12jcw/public_html/profile.php on line 17

line 17 is 

 $result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or die(mysql_error($db_server));

Comment: Why are you mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli` functions ?

Comment: Apologies, I'm not. I'm only using mysqli functions.

Comment: From your code.. `die(mysql_error($db_server))` <---- this is not `mysqli`.